# Why do I get "error: RPC failed; HTTP 408 curl 18 HTTP/2 stream 5 was reset" when trying to git push?

Tags: git, github

I tried to push my repository to my remote on GitHub , but I got this error:

```
error: RPC failed; HTTP 408 curl 18 HTTP/2 stream 5 was reset
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I used this command:

```bash
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

but it doesn't work; I also tried with another network and it gave me the same result.

Comment: [See the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer) for what `http.postBuffer` actually does, why you should never need it, and why setting it just wastes memory.

Comment: HTTP 408 is a request timeout - specifically, the server disconnected because it hadn't heard from your system in some period of time. What other config options have you set? What's in this repo (code, large binary assets, etc.)?